# How to get JSON reponse while POST of file data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, post

I am posting file data (image file) through AJAX and ASP.Net web services. I need to get JSON response like this: `({"d":"null"})`, but I am getting XML response, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">null</string>
```

I am converting response to JSON using `JavaScriptSerializer` in WebService before sending the response but it's not converting.

```
return js.Serialize(result);
```

I have also added following code at the top of Web Method.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
```

Following is the code to send file data uusing AJAX

```
if (bannerImage) {
    //var file = document.getElementById('bannerImage').files[0];
    var file = this.files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(file.name, file);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        url: url,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: onUpdateUserPhotoSuccess
    });
}
```

Comment: seems like web service returns xml

Comment: Yes, i am converting it in to JSON, but its still returning xml